# OPE coefficients and three-point function

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

I am trying to prove that the OPE coefficients $C_{ij}^k$ are the same as the normalization of the three-point fuction $\lambda_{ijk}$.
$$\frac{\lambda_{ijk}}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{23}|^{\Delta_j+\Delta_k-\Delta_i}|x_{13}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_k-\Delta_j}},$$
with $x_{ij}=x_i-x_j$. By interting an OPE expansion in the the three-point function I eventually get
$$\frac{C_{ij}^k}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}}\frac{1}{|x_{23}|^{2\Delta_k}}$$
and now I should be able to obtain $C_{ij}^k=\lambda_{ijk}$ by the equality of this two expressions, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried to rewrite $x_{13}$ as $x_{12}+x_{23}$ to only have the two variables, but I haven't managed to make it work. Any tips would be appreciated.

Edit: Thanks to the comments and links that were replied I think I finishe the derivation. I'll write the rest of it in case it is usefull for anyone in the future. If there are any mistakes let me know. By doing some easy manipulations we can get the right hand side to have the form

$$\frac{C_{ij}^k}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}}\frac{1}{|x_{32}|^{2\Delta_k}}(1+\ldots)=\frac{\kappa_{ijk}}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{32}|^{\Delta_j+\Delta_k-\Delta_i}}\frac{1}{|x_{12}-x_{32}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_k-\Delta_j}}\\
    =\frac{\kappa_{ijk}}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{32}|^{\Delta_j+\Delta_k-\Delta_i}}\frac{1}{|x_{32}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_k-\Delta_j}|\frac{x_{12}}{x_{32}}-1|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_k-\Delta_j}}\\
    =\frac{\kappa_{ijk}}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{32}|^{2\Delta_k}}\frac{1}{|\frac{x_{12}}{x_{32}}-1|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_k-\Delta_j}}.\\$$

Expanding the last term on the right hand side and keeping the first order only we get the result

$$\frac{C_{ij}^k}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}}\frac{1}{|x_{32}|^{2\Delta_k}}(1+\ldots)=\frac{\kappa_{ijk}}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{32}|^{2\Delta_k}}(1-(\Delta_i+\Delta_k-\Delta_j)(\frac{x_{12}}{x_{32}}-1)+\ldots)\\
\frac{C_{ij}^k}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{32}|^{2\Delta_k}}=\frac{\kappa_{ijk}}{|x_{12}|^{\Delta_i+\Delta_j-\Delta_k}|x_{32}|^{2\Delta_k}}$$

Comment: put in the details of how you inserted the OPE exansion and we can help you find the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OPE Coefficients from two and three point functions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/664668/)

Answer (score 2):

You only wrote the leading term of the OPE in the limit $x_1\to x_2$, so your two expressions should only agree to their leading order in that limit. And they do, after setting $x_{13}=x_{23}$ in the three-point function.